# Problem with \specialcomment-command and equation/align-environments

Tags: spacing, comments

I'm using the `specialcomment`-command from the [comment package](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/comment) around `equation` and `align` environments. This leads to an unwanted blank line after the math environment. When just using the simple `includecomment`-command, the problem does not show, neither when my special comment just encloses "normal" text. In my example, this doesn't look so bad. But in my actual document there are other settings so it just doesn't look good. Changing the spacing by `\specialcomment{mycomment2}{\color{red}}{\color{black}\vspace{-4ex}}` or something like that messes with the normal commented text.  How can I fix this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{comment}
\includecomment{mycomment1}
\specialcomment{mycomment2}{\color{red}}{\color{black}}
\begin{document}
\begin{mycomment1}
\begin{equation}
x=y
\end{equation}
\end{mycomment1}

\blindtext

\begin{mycomment2}
\begin{equation}
x=y
\end{equation}
\end{mycomment2}

\blindtext

\begin{mycomment2}
Just some normal text, no problem there.
\end{mycomment2}

\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Edit: It seems that a bit of code I left out in order to make the problem as simple as possible is relevant after all. My code regarding the equations is actually like this:

```
\begin{mycomment2}
\begin{equation}
x=y
\end{equation}
\end{mycomment2}
%
\begin{flushleft}
Text
\end{flushleft}
\blindtext
```

In this case there is an extra blank line even though there are none in the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't actually caused by the `comment` package, it's the colour change, as you can see from this example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
x=y
\end{equation}

\blindtext

\color{red}
\begin{equation}
x=y
\end{equation}
\color{black}

%
\blindtext

\color{red}
Just some normal text, no problem there.
\color{black}

\blindtext
\end{document}
```

To eliminate the problem with blank lines, replace `\color{black}` with `\vskip0pt\color{black}\noindent`. However, the colouring macros will still cause trouble if a `mycomment2` is followed by an environment that begins a new line, and I am not aware of any general solution. @David Carlisle gives a good explanation of the problem and a workaround [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47053/2417).

Comment: Thanks, but that solution doesn't work for me, because the blank lines in my code are there to make paragraphs. If I chose to use `\excludecomment{mycomment2}` at some point, these paragraphs would no longer exist. It would just be one big bulk of text.

Comment: @meep.meep --- I have edited my answer. Does it work now?

Comment: Note that this solution doesn’t work if `\begin{mycomment2}\begin{equation}...\end{equation}\end{mycomment2}` is followed by `\begin{flushleft}...\end{flushleft}.`

Answer (score 0):

If the special comment `mycomment2` always constitutes a separate paragraph try:

```
\makeatletter

\specialcomment{mycomment2}{%
  \par\begingroup\color{red}%
}{%
  \par\global\@tempskipa\lastskip\removelastskip\endgroup\vskip\@tempskipa%
}

\makeatother
```

Unfortunately, using `\color` can easily degrade vertical spacing. The critical internal macros are `\set@color` and `\reset@color`. Since they are driver-dependent it might be difficult to find a general fix to the vertical spacing problems induced by them.