# colored column in tabularx

Tags: spacing, color, tabularx

In a tabularx, I try to set the text color for a complete column as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[papersize={60mm,60mm},margin=5mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array,xcolor,colortbl,tabularx,ragged2e}
\pagestyle{empty}\parindent0pt
\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{50mm}[t]{|
  >{\color{blue}\hsize=.7\hsize\RaggedLeft}X|
  >{\hsize=.3\hsize}X
|}\hline
Hello & World\\
Hello & World\\\hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

How can I prevent the the `\color{blue}` to cause extra white space in the top of each cell?
[image]

Comment: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47050/how-does-changing-colour-affect-spacing and then you can use `\leavevmode\color{blue}`

Comment: @cmhughes since Harish has deleted his answer could you make this comment an answer:-) (extra points if you include  **It's not David's fault** in the text)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle you're very generous, but I feel that you deserve the rep :) please post an answer, I'll happily vote for it. Unless, of course, you consider it a duplicate? If so, do you have a golden hammer that allows you to close?

Comment: @cmhughes no hammer, but voted

Comment: On reflection, I'm not entirely sure the question is a duplicate. The answer is the same, but not the question...