# \addxcontentsline causes empty to part of mdframed box before page break

Tags: table-of-contents, page-breaking, mdframed, write

I’m using `mdframed` to surround an own environment called `{myenv}` (for this example). And this environment is setup as a trio list and uses `\addxcontentsline` to write a list of these environments (I’m using `doc` only for the MWE).

**Problem**

[image: problem]

The box is broken across pages leaving an empty top part on the first page.

**Code/MWE**

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage[framemethod = TikZ]{mdframed}

\ExplSyntaxOn\makeatletter

% define a style
\mdfdefinestyle { mystyle } {
   backgroundcolor = yellow,
   innertopmargin = 0.55\baselineskip,
   skipabove = 1\baselineskip \@plus 1ex,
}

% define the environment
\NewDocumentEnvironment { myenv } { } {
   \list { } { }
      \item \relax
      \addxcontentsline { toc } { myenv } [ X ] { }% <---------------- [A]
      { \bfseries My~Env~No.~X }% <----------------------------------- [B]
      \par \nopagebreak
} {
   \endlist
}
% souround it with an md frame
\surroundwithmdframed[ style = mystyle ] { myenv }

%% for testing
%\long\def\protected@write#1#2#3{%
%      \begingroup
%       \let\uthepage\relax
%       #2%
%       \let\protect\@unexpandable@protect
%       \edef\reserved@a{\write#1{#3}}% <------+---------------------- [C]
%       \reserved@a% <-------------------------'
%      \endgroup
%      \if@nobreak\ifvmode\nobreak\fi\fi
%}

\ExplSyntaxOff\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
   \lipsum[1] \vspace{110mm} \lipsum[2]
   \begin{myenv}
      \lipsum*[2]
   \end{myenv}
\end{document}
```

It dosen’t happen when I

- remove (or comment out) line marked with `[A]` **or**
- remove (or comment out) line marked with `[B]` (not sure about this one, though) **or**
- switch order of lines `[A]` and `[B]`

Furthermore I traced the problem back to `\protected@write`: When deleting (commenting out) the two lines marked with `[C]` the problem disappears too.

**Questions**

1. What is the best solution for this problem? Can I switch `[A]` and `[B]` without problems?
2. Is this a bug in `mdframed` that should be reported?

**Notes**

- The original definition for `{myenv}` is more complex.
- I’m aware of `\newmdenv` and `\newmdtheoremenv` but I can’t use them for this.
- Shifting line `[A]` before `\list` doesn’t make a difference.

Comment: If I switch A and B, I get a warning about the box not being splittable, caused by the `\nopagebreak` command.

Comment: @egreg: Thanks! I overlooked that warning …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same would arise with `\color{green}` in place of `\addxcontentsline { toc } { myenv } [ X ] { }`. Try to issue first `\leavevmode` after `\item\relax`.

Comment: Thanks! But adding it causes the same warning @egreg mentioned above. The box actually is splittable (try `\lipsum*[2-10]`). Is there a proper way to get rid of the warning?

Comment: The warning comes from the `\nopagebreak` in your environment. If you remove it, there will be no warning, but the box will split. What is you objective ? it seems `\nopagebreak` achieves exactly what you want, but `mdframed` is polite enough to tell you it wishes it could have split the box. If you put the box earlier in the page (try `\lipsum[1] \vspace{95mm} \lipsum[2]`) the box will be split and there will be no warning of mdframed, because `\nopagebreak` did not contradict what it esteemed to be the best.

Comment: The `\nopagebreak` should prevent the title from being separated from the fist line of the text, therefor I wouldn’t omit it. So the warning doesn’t have anything to do with the `\leavevmode` and just aries because with added `\leavevmode` the `\nopagebreak` is evaluated?

Comment: The warning has nothing to do with `\leavevmode`. You have inserted a `\nopagebreak` at a location where `mdframed` wants to split the box in your mwe. It complains about it that's all. Shift the box to some other location and you get no complaints. (a warning is just a warning: your `\nopagebreak` forces mdframed to leave the previous page with some unfilled area at bottom).

Comment: Ok, thanks again! I accept your answer but I’d appreciate if you could add some explanation about why the `\leavevmode` solves the problem.

Comment: One component of the underlying mechanism is commented upon there: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47053/4686.