# Why does the \color-command eliminate/decrease vertical spacing?

Tags: color, vertical-spacing

I have been wrecking my brain to figure out why some elements are too high above the horizontal line/rule and some are arguably well placed.

I found out it is because of the `\color`-command.

Why does that happen?

How can I have the parts without the `\color`-command behave the same way as it were there?

## Screenshot of MWE

[image]

## MWE

```
\documentclass[
11pt,
a4paper,
]
{scrartcl}

\usepackage{
lmodern,
multicol,
}

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\listfiles

\begin{document}
\begin{center}\huge
Title stuff
\end{center}

\begin{multicols*}{2}
\section{Word}


\begin{center}
\sffamily
\fbox{
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.9\columnwidth}
\centering\begin{minipage}[t]{0.95\columnwidth}\raggedright%
\color{DarkBlue}\textbf{Stuff:} aaaaaaaa [asdf: 1111]
\end{minipage}\par\addvspace{0.4ex}%
\color{black}\rule{0.9\columnwidth}{0.1pt}\par\addvspace{0.4ex}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.95\columnwidth}\small
Words.

Sentence words and aaaa asdf lorem.
Ipsum.
Words words more.
\end{minipage}
\end{minipage}}
\end{center}


\begin{center}
\sffamily
\fbox{
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.9\columnwidth}
\centering\begin{minipage}[t]{0.95\columnwidth}\raggedright%
\textbf{Stuff:} aaaaaaaa [asdf: 1111]
\end{minipage}\par\addvspace{0.4ex}%
\color{black}\rule{0.9\columnwidth}{0.1pt}\par\addvspace{0.4ex}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.95\columnwidth}\small
Words.

Sentence words and aaaa asdf lorem.
Ipsum.
Words words more.
\end{minipage}
\end{minipage}}
\end{center}

\end{multicols*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: texdoc grfguide  footnote page 6

Comment: [Related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47050/2417).

Comment: @IanThompson ooh I gave same answer (more or less:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike a font change, `\color` adds a node into the document and it is hard in all cases to avoid that node affecting spacing. (There is a footnote on page 6 of grfguide which can be summarised as "it's not my fault").

It is usually easier to get understandable behaviour if the colour whatsit is inserted in horizontal rather than vertical mode. `\textcolor` uses `\leavevmode` at the start (like all latex box commands) to ensure this. Uising `\textcolor` in your example you get the same spacing in each case.

```
\documentclass[
11pt,
a4paper,
]
{scrartcl}

\usepackage{
lmodern,
multicol,
}

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\listfiles

\begin{document}
\begin{center}\huge
Title stuff
\end{center}

\begin{multicols*}{2}
\section{Word}


\begin{center}
\sffamily
\fbox{%%%%%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.9\columnwidth}
\centering\begin{minipage}[t]{0.95\columnwidth}\raggedright
\textcolor{DarkBlue}{\textbf{Stuff:} aaaaaaaa [asdf: 1111]}%
\end{minipage}\par\addvspace{0.4ex}%
\textcolor{black}{\rule{0.9\columnwidth}{0.1pt}}\par\addvspace{0.4ex}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.95\columnwidth}\small
Words.

Sentence words and aaaa asdf lorem.
Ipsum.
Words words more.
\end{minipage}
\end{minipage}}
\end{center}


\begin{center}
\sffamily
\fbox{%%%%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.9\columnwidth}
\centering\begin{minipage}[t]{0.95\columnwidth}\raggedright%
\textbf{Stuff:} aaaaaaaa [asdf: 1111]
\end{minipage}\par\addvspace{0.4ex}%
\textcolor{black}{\rule{0.9\columnwidth}{0.1pt}}\par\addvspace{0.4ex}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.95\columnwidth}\small
Words.

Sentence words and aaaa asdf lorem.
Ipsum.
Words words more.
\end{minipage}
\end{minipage}}
\end{center}

\end{multicols*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, David. Would you have a hint for my second question, i.e. which command I would have to use to yield the decrease in vertical spacing anyway? Note: If you prefer a new question, a note would suffice and I will make one for this.

Comment: @henry above the rule? You are adding space there, just add less eg change .4ex to `\addvspace{-1ex}%`  ?

Comment: Well it's a manual solution based on incremental checks... but it works. Thanks. :)