# Extra space when changing font color in minipage

Tags: color, minipage, parskip

Changing the font color at the beginning of a minipage seems to cause an extra `\parskip` of vertical space.  This doesn't happen if I instead make the text (for example) italic, nor if anything precedes the color change, as seen below.  Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Here's a demonstration:

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\fbox{\begin{minipage}{.5in}%
    \setlength{\parskip}{1cm}%
    \itshape text!%
\end{minipage}}%
\fbox{\begin{minipage}{.5in}%
    \setlength{\parskip}{1cm}%
    \color{red}text!%
\end{minipage}}%
\fbox{\begin{minipage}{.5in}%
    \setlength{\parskip}{1cm}%
    t\color{red}ext!%
\end{minipage}}%
\fbox{\begin{minipage}{.5in}%
    \setlength{\parskip}{1cm}%
    \vskip -\parskip%
    \color{red}text!%
\end{minipage}}%
\fbox{\begin{minipage}{.5in}%
    \setlength{\parskip}{1cm}%
    \hspace{0pt}%
    \color{red}text!%
\end{minipage}}

\end{document}
```

[image: Demonstration]

Comment: Upon further inspection, it seems like this answer is relevant, and that a less hack-y solution to my problem is to leave vertical mode with `\leavevmode` before changing the color. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/589156/114496

If anyone can elaborate, I'd still appreciate it.

Comment: You might want to consider writing, e.g., `\textcolor{red}{text!}` which will take care of the `\leavevmode` for you.

Answer (score -1):

You seem to have missed one command.

```
\vskip -\parskip %
```

See the below MWE:

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\fbox{\begin{minipage}{.5in}%
    \setlength{\parskip}{1cm}%
    \itshape text!%
 \end{minipage}}%
\fbox{\begin{minipage}{.5in}%
    \setlength{\parskip}{1cm}%
    \vskip -\parskip%
    \color{red} text!%
\end{minipage}}%
\fbox{\begin{minipage}{.5in}%
    \setlength{\parskip}{1cm}%
    \vskip -\parskip%
    \color{red}text!%
\end{minipage}}%
\fbox{\begin{minipage}{.5in}%
    \setlength{\parskip}{1cm}%
    \vskip -\parskip%
    \color{red}text!%
\end{minipage}}%
\fbox{\begin{minipage}{.5in}%
    \setlength{\parskip}{1cm}%
    \hspace{0pt}%
    \color{red}text!%
\end{minipage}}
\end{document}
```

I added the \vskip -\parskip% at the 13th and 18th line.
Hope this is helpful.
[image]