# How to prevent xspace creating a space between my macro and a trailing single 's' character?

Tags: xspace

I have defined a macro like that: `\newcommand{\code}[1]{\texttt{#1}\xspace}`

In some situations, I'd like to write the plural of some object and the trailing (plural) 's'-character should not be marked as code. So it should look like that: `ClassInstance`s.

However, when I do `\code{ClassInstance}s` I get an extra space, i.e. it will look like: `ClassInstance` s.

What can I do?

**Edit**

Considering @egreg's answer, it seems that I have left out an essential part of the macro. In fact, the definition of `\code` also modifies the text color. Only then the use of `\xspace` seems to be necessary at all.

In order to reproduce the issue, run this minimal example:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xspace}

\newcommand{\code}[1]{\texttt{#1}}
\newcommand{\colcode}[1]{\color{blue}\texttt{#1}\color{black}}
\newcommand{\colcodex}[1]{\color{blue}\texttt{#1}\color{black}\xspace}

\begin{document}
    Bounds are constructed by closed \code{Curve} objects.
    
    Bounds are constructed by closed \colcode{Curve} objects.
    
    Bounds are constructed by closed \colcodex{Curve} objects.

    Sometimes we have even two \colcodex{Curve}s.
\end{document}
```

From this I get:
[image]

Comment: Why using `\xspace` to begin with?

Comment: @egreg I started to use `\xspace` in order to allow a space between a `\code` macro and the next word, such as in `The \code{ClassInstance} is ...` which would yield an output without a space between "ClassInstance" and "is" without the `\xspace` command.

Comment: If you remove `\xspace` you'll see that the space is preserved.

Comment: Remark on the update, the actual issue is [color - How does changing colour affect spacing? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47050/how-does-changing-colour-affect-spacing) (although in this case the space *after*, not before, the \color is removed, so another option is to append `\leavevmode`... however that's *probably* what `\textcolor` already does behind the scene, so no need to reinvent the wheel)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only case, if any, where `\xspace` might be useful is when commands *that take no argument* are being defined.

Try with

```
\newcommand{\code}[1]{\texttt{#1}}
```

and you'll see that with

```
The \code{ClassInstance} is ... 

\code{ClassInstance}s
```

the space is preserved in the first case and not added in the second one.

To put it differently, `\xspace` ***must never*** be used when defining commands that take arguments.

---

**Update**

The `\colcode` command is wrongly defined: instead, do

```
\newcommand{\colcode}[1]{\textcolor{blue}{\texttt{#1}}}
```

which would avoid both the problem of space gobbling and the need to get back to the “previous” color.

Comment: Thanks for this important information. In fact, my command was slightly different from what I initially posted (I wanted to make it simpler). Please see the edited question.

Comment: @AmosEgel `\newcommand{\colcode}[1]{\textcolor{blue}{\texttt{#1}}}`. See the update