# How to make custom command work after line break/new paragraph?

Tags: color, line-breaking

I have a simple command which creates coloured text. This works without any issues when there is a single paragraph without a line break. With a linebreak/new paragraph this does not work (commented code in MWE below produces this).  The error that is given is

```
Too many }'s.
\tbn #1->\textcolor {blue}{{#1} }
```

A simple method is to use `\tbn{}` separately for each paragraph after line break. But can the command be redefined so that it works across paragraphs/line breaks?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\tbn}[1]{\textcolor{blue}{{#1}}}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\tbn{This works if there is no line break.}

% \tbn{This doesn't work if there is a line break.

% If there is a line break.}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\textcolor` doesn't accept paragraphs in its argument (just like all the other `\text...` commands like `\textbf`). Instead use an explicit group and `\color`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\tbn}[1]{\leavevmode{\color{blue}#1}}

\begin{document}
\tbn{This works if there is no line break.}

\tbn{This doesn't work if there is a line break.

If there is a line break.}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I would perhaps add a leavevmode

Comment: I would delete the "perhaps" from Ulrike's comment

Comment: Could you perhaps explain why `leavevmode` is needed?

Comment: @Damitr Because colour support isn't really built into TeX but added by using `\special` which outputs a whatsit that might have side effects if used in the wrong place, the `\leavevmode` reduces the risk of strange things.

Comment: @Damitr for a better explanation take a look here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47053/117050